# How can we enable these price category rule if any one have done this type of query then expalin step by step?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I have this type of query :-

1) buy 2 category A products & get discount 10% Discount on any B category products.
2) buy any category products total amount is 200 , you will get 10% discount.
2.1) buy any category products total amount is 300 to 500, you will get free shipping.

2.2)buy any category products total amount 500 or above, you will get free shipping & you will get 10% discount.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions for this (all tested and verified with 1.7.0.2)

@2.1) This is not possible with a single cart price rule. Because you need 3 different actions to achieve all of it
2.1.1: 2 from A => 10% for B: [image] and [image]

2.1.2: should be really easy to setup according the other examples given in here.

2.1.3: 300-500 from special categories : [image] and [image]

@2.2)

for the rules i would think of something like this: [image]

and for the action : [image]

Comment: Is it working for you like you intended?